# Url amigável e Url padrão php com parâmetros

Tags: url-amigável

Estou com uma dúvida e acredito que vocês poderão me ajudar.

Quero deixar funcionando os dois sistemas de URL em meu site, quero colocar amigável em algumas páginas e deixar a forma padrão em outra.

`pagina.php?nome=Bruno`

Alguém saberia me informar como configuro o `.htacces`s para que ele aceite os dois padrões ?

Eu já estou escondendo o .php com este código

```
RewriteEngine on<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode utilizar

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^nome/([^/]*)$ /?nome=$1 [L]
```

Isso ira retornar uma pagina desse tipo

```
pagina.php/nome/Bruno
```

Caso queira omitir o /nome/ pode utilizar

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?nome=$1 [L]
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá Bruno, obrigado pela resposta, o flag L vai deixar as outras url que eu não transformar em amigável funcionar ?

Obrigado

Comment: Hoje eu uso da seguinte forma user?user=12 e eu quero deixar user/12 ou user/nomedouser mas quero continuar usando nas outras páginas a forma antiga, e sem exibir o .php